# Printing a document from iOS?

Tags: ios4

What are some of the basic solutions for iOS 4 development that will allow me to print from a custom application? At this stage I'm just preparing an RFP so I just need the basics. (1) is it possible? (I'm assuming it is) and (2) what are some of the APIs or items I should be looking at to make it happen? The application will issue citations and I need to have an input screen and then a print button that prints the citation to a designated printer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newer iOS versions (>4.2) support printing through AirPrint:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/Printing/Printing.html